# Dynamically Add Multiple Javascript Function to .Net Control

Tags: asp.net

I just have a query I have a string which contain all the below function added to the string variable and i want to add this to a control for e.g textbox control. So how can i add this to a textbox control

`string strTextBoxScripts = " onclick="Func1();" onKeypress="Func2();" ";
textbox.attributes.add(strTextBoxScripts);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to inject some text directly into the HTML that gets rendered for an ASP.NET TextBox Control.

Try this instead:

```
 textbox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Func1();");
 textbox.Attributes.Add("onKeypress", "Func2();");
```

The ASP.NET Web Controls create a separation of concerns between the HTML that gets rendered by a control and all of the features and functionality that the ASP.NET TextBox control exposes to you as a programmer. Under the hood and invisible to you, when a user loads your ASP.NET Page it will execute the Render() function from the base Page class which will eventually call Render() on all the Controls on the page including your TextBox.

Only within that Render() function do you get anything that looks like the HTML you might be expecting:

```
 <input id="ctl00_textbox" onclick="Func1();" onKeypress="Func2();" />
```